# Laravel 5.2 custom authentication without database or model

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Laravel 5.2 custom authentication without database or model while data coming from a remote server that contains true or false

Comment: You're not using oauth or anything?  Laravel has documentation on oauth/social logins on their site.  If you really just have a "true" or "false" then a custom middleware and not utilizing Laravel's Auth classes is probably the best way.

Comment: No i am not using any kind of auth even laravel auth,i have a array that come from a remote server having true or false in that array , on base of that true and false i want to create session.I am new to laravel so is it right to use middleware for it as  @Felippe Duarte answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group the routes with custom auth middleware:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'myauth'], function() {
    Route::get('...');
    Route::post('...');
});
```

Then create a middleware:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class Myauth
{
    public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
    {
        if(session()->has('authenticated')) {
            return $next($request);    
        } else {
            return response('Unauthorized.', 401);
            //OR return redirect()->guest('/');
        }
    }
}
```

And in some point of your application you need to set the `session('authenticated', true)`

It's a way to go but your could choose a better approach like OAuth.

Comment: if i want to use auth than ?

Comment: I didn't understand your question

Comment: if i want to use Auth facade for login instead of this middleware solution

Comment: You can create your custom guard to do what you want. Take a look at laravel docs: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/authentication#adding-custom-guards

Comment: so while using custom guard can i avoid to validate data from database ?

Comment: Yes. Here you can get some example: http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/115/using-your-own-authentication-driver

Comment: let me try custom guard...but middleware solution is also a good option

Comment: This is how i put data array in session()->put('userData',$user). But when i check it on other page like in middle its vanish